# Determinant of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, definite-integrals, determinant, matrix-equations

I was thinking about matrices and then why arent there matrices with uncountable many values? (Probably this conecpt already exists for a very long time, but i don't know it)

Assume there are matrices $A$ and $B$ with the size $N\times N$. Then the product $C=A*B$ is defined as:
$$
C_{y,x}=\sum_{k=1}^N{A_{y,k}*B_{k,x}}
$$

Now this could to be done with an uncountable matrix (which is just a function):

$$
A(x,y)=x^2+y, B(x,y)=x*y
$$

for

$$
x, y\in[0,N]
$$

Then the value of $C=A*B$ ($*$ for the "special matrix multiplication") could be defined as:
$$
C(x,y)=\int\limits_0^N{A(k,y)*B(x,k)}\mathrm{d}k
$$

Now we can multiply two matrices with uncountable many values. There is also a neutral element which can be defined as $e(x,y)=\delta(x-y)$ (dirac delta function).

Of course also vector with uncountable many values could be defined:

$$
b(y)=exp(y)
$$

It is also no problem to define a multiplication of such a matrix and such a vector:

$$
A(x,y)=x^2+y, b(y)=exp(y)
$$
for
$$
x,y\in[0,N]
$$

$$
C(y)=A*b=\int\limits_0^N{A(y,k)*b(k)}\mathrm{d}k
$$

And now another thing could be defined. A simple equation ($A,b$ are known, $x$ is unknown):

$$
A(x,y)*x(y)=b(y)
$$

Or simpler:
$$
Ax=b
$$

Which is equal to:
$$
\int\limits_0^N{A(y,k)*x(k)}\mathrm{d}k=b(y)
$$

Now it is not obvious if such an equation has a solution or not. Is it possible to generalize the classic determinant to a function $f(x,y)$, where $x,y\in[0,N]$? So that it is possible to see if such an equation has a unique solution.

All things here were just copied from the classic linear algebra, so i think something like a determinant should also be available?

Thank you very much

best regards

Kevin

Comment: Your intuition is good (+1), though unfortunately including the "known for a long time" part: You've (re-)discovered [Fredholm integral operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_theory), see also general [integral equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_equation). :)

Comment: Except that the Dirac $\delta$ is not an actual function, of course, so you are going to have to jump into functional analysis and deal with distributions. Not sure if there is a determinant - there are three obvious ways of defining determinant in the finite dimension case - inductively, in terms of volume. or in terms of characteristic polynomials. All require finite dimensions.

Comment: Also, it is not clear your space is best represented as uncountably infinite-dimensional. To be integrable, functions need to be "nice," and this will often make it possible to find a countable basis. Particularly on a finite interval, you might be able to use polynomial basis, or the Fourier basis. So treating it as uncountable dimensional might be satisfying-seeming, the reality is you might still dealing with an essentially countably-infinite-dimensional space.

Comment: Thanks for the anwers, they are very helpful:) Especially for the "Fredholm integral operator" hint.